# add a value to pre-existing dictionary key in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql, gqlquery

I've been trying to add a value to a pre-existing dictionary key. The value comes from the db.Model `Car` with the property named `price`.

Tried two blocks of code (below) but have been getting the AttributeError: 'GqlQuery' object has no attribute 'price'.

```
items = {"BE1234":"2","BE1923":"3","BE2032":"1", etc}
------------------------------------------------------------
block 1)
for item in items:
  cars = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Car WHERE item=:1',item)
  items[item] = cars.price
------------------------------------------------------------
block 2)
for item in items:
  cars = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Car WHERE item=:1',item)
  items.update({item:cars.price})
```

What I'm looking to get is:

`items = {"BE1234":["2","100"],"BE1923":["31","200"],"BE2032":["19","300"], etc}`

**Update (final working code)**

```
for item in items:
  cars = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Car WHERE item=:1',item)
  for car in cars:
    items[item]=[items[item],str(car.price)]
```

Comment: make sure the query is not returning NONE and table car has a field price

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Construct a list (value) to be inserted and just update the value of a key: 
`items["BE1234"] = ["2", "100"]`

detailed (Shiva's comment has a "cleaner" way of doing the same thing):

```
current_val = items["BE1234"]
new_val = "100";
new_array = [current_val, new_val]
items["BE1234"] = new_array
```

Comment: `>>> items = {"BE1234":"2","BE1923":"3","BE2032":"1"}
>>> car_price=100
>>> items['BE1234']=[items['BE1234'],car_price]
>>> items
{'BE2032': '1', 'BE1234': ['2', 100], 'BE1923': '3'}`

Comment: quick question...would you happen to know how to call upon that value?? so if I have items = {"BE1234":["2","100"],"BE1923":["31","200"]}, how could I get the 100??

Comment: Iterate through the value of the list["2", "100"]